# Kivy, shade/shadow under widget

Tags: button, kivy, shadow

I want to know how can I achieve a button (in kivy) like the image that I have attached below. I want to know how to create a shade/shadow like this. I just need a hint to know where to start and what are the essentials.

Thanks

[kivy button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWRmV.png)

Answer (score 0):

The look of a `Button` is determined by its properties `background_normal`, `background_down`, `background_disabled_normal`, and `background_disabled_down`. Those are just strings naming the images that are used to represent the different states of the `Button`. So you can create new image files containing your desired look and just set those properties to those new files.

You can see the default `Button` images and how they are handled in the kivy `style.kv` and the `defaulttheme.atlas`.